# Mark [google-or-tools] as a synonym of [or-tools]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Looks like someone created the [google-or-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-or-tools) tag instead of using the original [or-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/or-tools) tag that actually has a wiki description.

It has a small userbase so I don't think the [synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/or-tools/synonyms) will gather enough votes.

Could you manually create the synonym for it?